# IIS7 is missing configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I'm trying to configure a new site.

I try to surf
and get the following error:

[image]

my web.config:
http://jsfiddle.net/3TnuG/

Comment: Show us your `web.config` file. Another thing: Is it an ASP.NET 4.0 site?

Comment: DotNet 3.5, you need the whol web.config? (it's long). btw, I have checked it online and its schema is valid

Comment: Did you open your web config files using any other editor?

Comment: Do you run it through IIS or through the internal VS web server?

Comment: @OferZelig IIS7, not VS server

Comment: Then check in IIS whether your site is running in Classic .Net AppPool, and try to switch between integrated and classic pipeline mode.

Comment: OK, my wild shot didn't work out. Did you check the second link that Ali Issa noted? Also check this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these two solution:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1149768.aspx

http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

Comment: could you flesh out the general theme of the answer here?

Comment: i didn't get u, can u plz explain what u mean

Comment: @AliIssa: This isn't an answer.  If you're confused about what is and is not an answer, and why link rot makes answers like this worthless, please take a look on [meta] for relevant posts.  Please [edit] this answer and flesh it out so that people don't have to leave to get the solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @AliIssa It says that the webconfig is malformed. I rechecked and even replaced with one that works for sure - but the same error appears